# Wait or revoking an iPhone expiring certificate?

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning

In my iOS Provisioning Portal `Current Development Certificates` section, the certificate expiry date is Sep 30, 2010. Today is Sep 30, 2010. Should I wait for the certificate to expire and renew? Or should I revoke the existing one and create a new one certificate?

Currently, the Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile has expired. No matter how many times I click the Renew button next to it, the status will become Expired. The means the app in all my beta testers' machines stops running and I cannot send a new version to them before a good Certificate is issued.

Thanks!

Comment: have you contacted the developer support about the renew problem? the answer needs some time but if you use your support incidents, you get feedback within 48 hours

Comment: My certificates expired, and I resubmitted my `CertificateSigningRequest` to get a new set of certificates. Once the new certificates are created, I can renew my provision profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can renew certificates before they expire, and this is typically a good idea.  There's really nothing to be gained by letting them go, except (a) if you're not actively using them, you save a few steps and (b) a few days before expiration, next year.

However, for normal use, you just renew them a week or two before they expire.

Comment: And how do you renew? Do you start with revoking the current developer certificate, and then create a new one? If I do that today, will the new developer certificate end 12/12-2013 or 10/12-2013? My current developer certificate ends 12/12, and my AdHoc distribution certificate moans about that...